# Could or has a Ninth planet ever be "formed" in our solar system?

Tags: solar-system, planetary-formation

As I get along with the answers in my previous [question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48295/which-planet-came-first-in-our-solar-system), that planet formation depends on accumulation of planetesimals. So is there any chance that a planet nine would form or any of the [Trans-Neptunian Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Neptunian_object), "evolve" into a planet in or near [the Kuiper Belt, which is thought to be a belt of planetesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuiper_belt)?

Although we don't know fully about the Kuiper belt, what can we conclude from the information and models we have now.

https://www.space.com/16080-solar-system-planets.html

Comment: As far as we know, there's not a lot of matter in the Kuiper belt, and it's mostly spread very thinly. Bear in mind that our Moon is almost 6 times heavier than Pluto. OTOH, it was kinda surprising when we discovered several largish trans-Neptunian bodies, so there could be more stuff hiding out there in the dark.

Comment: @PM2Ring I agree !

Comment: The largest TNOs are still dwarf planets. Search for 'hypothetical ninth planet' here to have a more insight.

Comment: Do not assume the planets of our solar system have always occupied the orbits they current have. Years ago I came across information that mentioned that Jupiter was once closer to the Sun & it moved to its current orbit. **If** the mysterious ninth planet exists it *might* have formed closer in & got flung out to a more distance orbit.

Comment: The question specifies formation in the Kuiper belt.